# Should I use Serverless or Kubernetes or Docker Swarm?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

We have a product that each device will report data to our server every minute, we've sold 10K and it'll be more than 100K within the next 2 years.

Now, we just use `AWS EC2`(8 CPUs) + `Nginx` + `Koa2`, there're 8 instances, according to the requirement increasing, it won't be appropriate anymore.

So, I'm confused about which one should I choose?

BTW, I've been using `AWS Lambda` for 2 years to develop IOT issues and I used Docker 5 years ago, I think all of these three ways can solve my issue.

Comment: We are currently using kubernetes, and it allow seamless scale up.. Please do start using at early stages.. This might help in later stages of production deployment

Comment: @Gokul Could you please tell me more about your project?

Comment: Yeah.. We are basically a big data processing company.
Out software stack includes Spark, Cassandra, redis, Postgres, NodeJS etc..
We create on demand spark clusters based on the requirement of the job using kubernetes and docker.
Cassandra too, we occasionally scale up or down..
We use poststop, prestop hook to distribute data before node removal for cassandra.. Watsapp me at 9789820759 for further discussions/clarifications/suggestions..

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes is a great tool if you are not sure how your application is going to scale out. Using Amazon's Kubernetes engine or GCP equivalent Kubernetes engine can help you create and manage these clusters with click of few buttons and manage your application containers using Kubernetes's superior container orchestration framework.

Docker swarm , IMO , has lost to kubernetes because they did not seem to have jumped into this part of architecture soon enough and kubernetes has already created a very mature framework with great adoption in many production environments and lot of community support for any issues related to it.

Another advantage of using an Orchestration mechanism instead of AWS native services would be that you do not get into Vendor lock-in situations and you can move your stack to any other cloud platform hosting Kubernetes easily.

If you are also interested in continue to use your Serverless architecture , you might want to look at Open FAAS which can be leverage on top of your Kubernetes framework. Check [this](https://docs.openfaas.com/deployment/kubernetes/) link for more details.

Comment: AWS-Serverless is also flexible scaling, why should I use both Kubernetes and Serverless if I already use Serverless?

Comment: It completely depends on your use-case , btw if you believe all your scenarios can be managed by Serverless architecture , you can very well go ahead and use AWS-Serverless and some backend AWS services , but in reality, it is rarely the case with large scale products, as they need some sort of custom components to be built. Also , consider that this will be completely locked-in to AWS ( not that anything is wrong with it ) , it is just matter of choice and your future scope of work.